# Does anyone know the difference between assignment in computing and equals in maths?

Tags: algorithms

i am a software engineer interested in maths. I've not got the skills or knowledge of maths to know the answer to the following question and i am hoping that someone could help me?

In programming languages a lot of concepts correspond very closely to certain math concepts for example; a for loop can be understood as a series, a data structure can be viewed as a cartesian product and a list can be seen as a sequence.

Basic algorithms use notation to specify computations where the operator ':=' represents the assignment operation. The assignment operator which completely copies the value of one variable to another (see example algorithm 1).

I am wondering what the relation (or difference) between the ':=' assignment operator and the '=' equality or 'let X be Y' or 'X is Y' math concepts?

```
int a;

int b;

a := 10;       // a = 10, b = undefined

b := a;        // a = 10, b = 10

b := b + 1;    // a = 10, b = 11
```

*[example algorithm 1]*

Answer (score 3):

Consider your last example $b:=b+1$.  In computing, this is not an equation but an instruction.  It means "take the present value of $b$, add $1$, make that the new value of $b$".

The equation $b=b+1$ means that $b$ and $b+1$ are the same number, which is impossible.

(No quibbles about mod $1$ arithmetic please.)

Comment: If we disalloweded self assignment, would the assignment operator and the equals sign from maths behave identically?

Comment: Also: do you know any references that might help me understand the maths more?

Comment: @RichardBamford re: "behave identically" - no, the fundamental difference would still be the same.  An assignment is an instruction telling you to do something, an equation is a statement which is either true or false.

Comment: Re: reference: not sure, perhaps just try any elementary algebra text.

Comment: @RichardBamford In other words, mathematical "=" is the programmist's "==".